# PHP Mysql display necessary records from two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `brp_consume_log` and `brp_transfer_log`, I joined both table with query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM brp_consume_log a
JOIN brp_transfer_log b ON b.acct_id = a.acct_id
WHERE a.acct_id ='1657'
```

result output as:

[image: join tables]

I would like to show the results in below format:

[image]

is it possible?

**UPDATE**
I've been able to use query below to output results that I want:

```
SELECT 
    datetime, 
    remark, 
    intake, 
    consume 
FROM
  (
    SELECT datetime, remark, points_intake intake, NULL consume, 1 ord
    FROM brp_transfer_log
    WHERE acct_id = '1657'
    UNION ALL

    SELECT datetime, remark, NULL, point_consume, 2
    FROM brp_consume_log
    WHERE acct_id = '1657'
  ) q
ORDER BY datetime DESC, ord
```

[image]

By the way, how do I add another field for `balance points` and do necessary subtraction or addition from last balance points?

Please advise. thanks!

Comment: what is the criteria of Action, Existing point calculation?

Comment: the desired output bears no resemblance to the data displayed by your queries

Comment: and which date do you want to use? table1 or 2? dont know

Comment: Both date are use, there are duplicate date after table joined. the `Action` is represent the number of points deduction or points add. Existing Points means the balance of the points.

Comment: but still your desired output not matching, plz add the column ID to